centred the contextmenu above the selected text
I want my contextMenu to be above and centred to my selected text and i want my buttons to be in a row. So it should basically look like an regular tooltip
Thanks
TextFormField(
  controller: MyTextEditingController(dataKey, text: widget.data),
  minLines: 4,
  contextMenuBuilder:
      (BuildContext context, EditableTextState editableTextState) {
        List<ContextMenuButtonItem> buttonItems =
        editableTextState.contextMenuButtonItems;
    buttonItems.insert(0,
      ContextMenuButtonItem(
        onPressed: () {
          ContextMenuController.removeAny();

        },
        label: 'dictionary',
      )
    );
    return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.buttonItems(
      anchors: editableTextState.contextMenuAnchors,
      buttonItems: buttonItems,
    );
  }, 
  inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(1000)],
  maxLines: null,
  onChanged: (text) {
    widget.data = text;
  },

);

